# Putting and android app in background and bringing in it back to foreground for android testing

Tags: android, testing, junit, functional-programming, robotium

Im doing functional testing on Android application using Robotium.

Trying to create a test case where
1. Activity starts, does some work.
2. Goes to background. 
3. Another Activity sends and intent, brings it back to foreground. does some more work.

Im able to put my Application in the background, but im not able to bring it back to foreground.